# in org-mode, how to make code blocks folded by default?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

In Emacs org-mode, how would I instruct org-mode to make HTML code blocks folded by default? So that when I open an org file they are folded?

Comment: Please see a related thread where I resolved the issue of completely hiding the `:PROPERTIES:` drawer in org-mode, along with tab-cycling for all available folding options:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/17492723/2112489   Your issue is very similar -- you would need a regexp for the beginning and ending regions of the code to be folded, and you could add that to the function in the above-mentioned link.

Comment: I see how to enter `#+BEGIN_HTML` as a regexp, but where would I enter `#+END_HTML`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

org-mode provides this feature out of the box. You can set it globally by customizing the variable `org-hide-block-startup`. To set this for a single file, add

```
#+STARTUP: hideblocks
```

To the header. Here's the relevant section of the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/Blocks.html)

Comment: While @lawlist's solution is a nice piece of work, this is a simpler solution, and also allows to hide/unhide with the TAB key.

Comment: "configuring the variable org-hide-block-startup" what does that mean? What values are possible?

Comment: @Xerus `C-h v org-hide-block-startup` will give you the help for the variable, including a link to the customization page. The customization system is described here: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Easy-Customization.html#Easy-Customization

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. This collapses all block, not all HTML blocks