# Org-mode Source Block Visibility Cycling

Tags: emacs, org-mode, org-babel

I'm trying to add source blocks to the visibility cycling tree. Essentially I want a source block to be treated as a child of its heading. Consider the following org-mode document:

```
* Heading 1
** Heading 2
#+BEGIN_SRC R
print("hello world")
#+END_SRC
** Heading 3
```

I would like to be able to press TAB on heading one to cycle through the folding of the various parts including the source block. Currently org-mode does seem to have the facilities for folding the source block, because I can fold that if I go to #+BEGIN_SRC R and hit tab, but it doesnt seem to be being treated in the global cycling. Any suggestions to add it?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if that is built-in, but here is a link to a modification I did for html blocks and footnotes:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/21594242/2112489  See also, this related thread:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/21563210/2112489

Comment: Ok i'm looking through your code and trying to piece this together. Since BEGIN_SRC blocks already fold, all that I need to do it seems is to modify org-cycle-internal-local in a similar way to what you did. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I would try the variable mentioned in the second link and see if that does the trick before looking at the first idea.  I should have placed the second link first in time . . . sorry.

Comment: That variable folds the blocks, but cycling of the blocks still doesn't work. I'll try to piece together something from your code. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a slight modification of the code contained in the link mentioned in my first comment above:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/21594242/2112489

All I did was replace the begin / end html regexp for the `SRC` regexp.  Go ahead and give it a whirl and see if it is what you're looking for.  I left my prior footnote modification in there.

```lisp
(require 'org)

(defalias 'org-cycle-hide-drawers 'lawlist-block-org-cycle-hide-drawers)

(defun lawlist-block-org-cycle-hide-drawers (state)
  "Re-hide all drawers, footnotes or html blocks after a visibility state change."
  (when
    (and
      (derived-mode-p 'org-mode)
      (not (memq state '(overview folded contents))))
    (save-excursion
      (let* (
          (globalp (memq state '(contents all)))
          (beg (if globalp (point-min) (point)))
          (end
            (cond
              (globalp
                (point-max))
              ((eq state 'children)
                (save-excursion (outline-next-heading) (point)))
              (t (org-end-of-subtree t)) )))
        (goto-char beg)
        (while
          (re-search-forward
            ".*\\[fn\\|^\\#\\+BEGIN_SRC.*$\\|^[ \t]*:PROPERTIES:[ \t]*$" end t)
          (lawlist-org-flag t))))))

(defalias 'org-cycle-internal-local 'lawlist-block-org-cycle-internal-local)

(defun lawlist-block-org-cycle-internal-local ()
  "Do the local cycling action."
  (let ((goal-column 0) eoh eol eos has-children children-skipped struct)
    (save-excursion
      (if (org-at-item-p)
        (progn
          (beginning-of-line)
          (setq struct (org-list-struct))
          (setq eoh (point-at-eol))
          (setq eos (org-list-get-item-end-before-blank (point) struct))
          (setq has-children (org-list-has-child-p (point) struct)))
        (org-back-to-heading)
        (setq eoh (save-excursion (outline-end-of-heading) (point)))
        (setq eos (save-excursion (1- (org-end-of-subtree t t))))
        (setq has-children
          (or
            (save-excursion
              (let ((level (funcall outline-level)))
                (outline-next-heading)
                (and
                  (org-at-heading-p t)
                  (> (funcall outline-level) level))))
            (save-excursion
              (org-list-search-forward (org-item-beginning-re) eos t)))))
      (beginning-of-line 2)
      (if (featurep 'xemacs)
        (while
            (and
              (not (eobp))
              (get-char-property (1- (point)) 'invisible))
          (beginning-of-line 2))
        (while
            (and
              (not (eobp))
              (get-char-property (1- (point)) 'invisible))
          (goto-char (next-single-char-property-change (point) 'invisible))
          (and
            (eolp)
            (beginning-of-line 2))))
      (setq eol (point)))
    (cond
      ((= eos eoh)
        (unless (org-before-first-heading-p)
          (run-hook-with-args 'org-pre-cycle-hook 'empty))
        (org-unlogged-message "EMPTY ENTRY")
        (setq org-cycle-subtree-status nil)
        (save-excursion
          (goto-char eos)
          (outline-next-heading)
          (if (outline-invisible-p)
            (org-flag-heading nil))))
      ((and
          (or
            (>= eol eos)
            (not (string-match "\\S-" (buffer-substring eol eos))))
          (or
            has-children
            (not (setq children-skipped
              org-cycle-skip-children-state-if-no-children))))
        (unless (org-before-first-heading-p)
          (run-hook-with-args 'org-pre-cycle-hook 'children))
        (if (org-at-item-p)
          ;; then
          (org-list-set-item-visibility (point-at-bol) struct 'children)
          ;; else
          (org-show-entry)
          (org-with-limited-levels (show-children))
          (when (eq org-cycle-include-plain-lists 'integrate)
            (save-excursion
              (org-back-to-heading)
              (while (org-list-search-forward (org-item-beginning-re) eos t)
                (beginning-of-line 1)
                (let* (
                    (struct (org-list-struct))
                    (prevs (org-list-prevs-alist struct))
                    (end (org-list-get-bottom-point struct)))
                  (mapc (lambda (e) (org-list-set-item-visibility e struct 'folded))
                    (org-list-get-all-items (point) struct prevs))
                  (goto-char (if (< end eos) end eos)))))))
        (org-unlogged-message "CHILDREN")
        (save-excursion
          (goto-char eos)
          (outline-next-heading)
          (if (outline-invisible-p)
            (org-flag-heading nil)))
        (setq org-cycle-subtree-status 'children)
        (unless (org-before-first-heading-p)
          (run-hook-with-args 'org-cycle-hook 'children)))
      ((or
          children-skipped
          (and
            (eq last-command this-command)
            (eq org-cycle-subtree-status 'children)))
        (unless (org-before-first-heading-p)
          (run-hook-with-args 'org-pre-cycle-hook 'subtree))
        (outline-flag-region eoh eos nil)
        (org-unlogged-message
        (if children-skipped
          "SUBTREE (NO CHILDREN)"
          "SUBTREE"))
        (setq org-cycle-subtree-status 'subtree)
        (unless (org-before-first-heading-p)
          (run-hook-with-args 'org-cycle-hook 'subtree)))
      ((eq org-cycle-subtree-status 'subtree)
        (org-show-subtree)
        (message "ALL")
        (setq org-cycle-subtree-status 'all))
      (t
        (run-hook-with-args 'org-pre-cycle-hook 'folded)
        (outline-flag-region eoh eos t)
        (org-unlogged-message "FOLDED")
        (setq org-cycle-subtree-status 'folded)
        (unless (org-before-first-heading-p)
        (run-hook-with-args 'org-cycle-hook 'folded))))))

(defun lawlist-org-flag (flag)
  "When FLAG is non-nil, hide any of the following:  html code block;
footnote; or, the properties drawer.  Otherwise make it visible."
  (save-excursion
    (beginning-of-line 1)
    (cond
      ((looking-at ".*\\[fn")
        (let* (
          (begin (match-end 0))
          end-footnote)
          (if (re-search-forward "\\]"
                (save-excursion (outline-next-heading) (point)) t)
            (progn
              (setq end-footnote (point))
              (outline-flag-region begin end-footnote flag))
            (user-error "Error beginning at point %s." begin))))
      ((looking-at "^\\#\\+BEGIN_SRC.*$\\|^[ \t]*:PROPERTIES:[ \t]*$")
        (let* ((begin (match-end 0)))
          (if (re-search-forward "^\\#\\+END_SRC.*$\\|^[ \t]*:END:"
                (save-excursion (outline-next-heading) (point)) t)
            (outline-flag-region begin (point-at-eol) flag)
            (user-error "Error beginning at point %s." begin)))))))

(defun lawlist-toggle-block-visibility ()
"For this function to work, the cursor must be on the same line as the regexp."
(interactive)
  (if
      (save-excursion
        (beginning-of-line 1)
          (looking-at
            ".*\\[fn\\|^\\#\\+BEGIN_SRC.*$\\|^[ \t]*:PROPERTIES:[ \t]*$"))
    (lawlist-org-flag (not (get-char-property (match-end 0) 'invisible)))
    (message "Sorry, you are not on a line containing the beginning regexp.")))
```

Comment: Glad to help.  The footnote code only contemplated one (1) footnote per heading, and needs to be improved upon.  Please feel free to remove the footnote code, or improve upon it if you like.

Comment: This introduces some strange 'dependent lightswitch' behavior: While you can unfold the code block from it's headline, you can't unfold it from the source code block line anymore. but if you try once, then the unfolding from the headline doesn't work anymore until you 'switch' it on the code block line again. At least that's what I'm experiencing