# How can I make org-mode store state changes for a repeating task in a drawer?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Basically, I have a lot of tasks that are set to repeat and I like keeping records of what days they actually get done, but the recorded state changes don't collapse nicely. Is there some way to make emacs store them in a drawer or some other structure that's collapsible?

EDIT:

org-version 8.2.7

Comment: Doesn't it get stored in a collapsible log drawer?  What's your org version?

Comment: If so, it's not collapsible with TAB. Org version 8.2.7.

Comment: Here is a link to a related thread, that contains other links, to some things I wrote modifying org-cycle so that I completely hide the properties drawer, including the word `:PROPERTIES:` and I hide footnotes.  If org-mode does not have the feature you seek, you could write something similar to what I did in those links.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/21594242/2112489  It may behoove you to revise your question and include an example of what it looks like now, and also what you would like it to look like if such a thing were possible.  Someone may be able to help if they have a clear picture.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an option called `org-log-into-drawer` ([doc here](http://orgmode.org/worg/doc.html#org-log-into-drawer)) to control this.

If set to non-nil, all state changes and notes will be added to a drawer.

You can even control the order in which changes are recorded with `org-log-states-order-reversed`.

More info [in the manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Tracking-TODO-state-changes.html#Tracking-TODO-state-changes).

Comment: Thanks. I looked at the manual, but missed that line near the top describing what I wanted.