# FiveThirtyEight style in-text footnotes for bookdown

Tags: javascript, css, r-markdown, pandoc, bookdown

I'm creating a project using {[bookdown](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown)}, and I would like to format my footnotes to appear directly in the text when the superscript is selected, as happens in FiveThirtyEight articles (see [here](https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/how-much-money-do-mlb-players-really-make/) for an example). The idea is that when a user clicks on the footnotes, the paragraph expands to show the footnote text, and then compresses back to normal when the footnote is closed.

I have found a few resources where this is implemented:

- Stackoverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40336366/in-line-footnotes-with-only-html-css-in-notes)
- https://medium.com/@bnjmnbnjmn/in-line-notes-with-only-html-css-f181c5ceef59
- https://www.viget.com/articles/of-note-better-text-annotations-for-the-web/

However, these solutions all seem to assume that the actual footnote text is within a `<span>` tag that has an associated class. However, this does not appear to be the case for HTML footnotes generated from {bookdown} and Pandoc. The HTML looks like this:

```html
<p>
  "Figures and tables with captions will be placed in "
  <code>
    "figure
  </code>
  " and "
  <code>
    "table"
  </code>
  " environments, respectively."
  <a href="#fn1" class="footnote-ref" id = "fnref1"><sup>1</sup></a>
</p>

<div class="footnotes">
  <hr>
  <ol start="1">
    <li id="fn1">
      <p>
        "Here is a fancy footnote."
        <a href="intro.html#fnref1" class="footnote-back">"<-"</a>
      </p>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

So not only are the footnotes placed in an unclassed `<p>` tag, rather than a classed `<span>` tag, the footnotes themselves are also in a completely separate `<div>`, rather than appearing within the same tag as the rest of the text, as is the case in the linked examples.

I've created a bookdown reprex to try and make this work with a combination of CSS and javascript, based on the linked examples above. The GitHub repo is [here](https://github.com/wjakethompson/bd-reprex/blob/master/01-intro.Rmd), and the rendered output [here](https://bd-reprex.netlify.app/intro.html#fn1). I've successfully hidden the footnotes at the bottom of the page, but have not been able to get the footnotes to display in-text when the footnote superscript is selected.

Is there a way to style footnotes in this way using {bookdown}? Or is this a constraint of Pandoc?

Comment: a while ago I solved this [with some javascript](https://github.com/mb21/api-explorer/blob/gh-pages/a-web-based-tool-to-semi-automatically-import-data-from-generic-rest-apis.html#L122)... this is [the HTML output](http://mb21.github.io/api-explorer/a-web-based-tool-to-semi-automatically-import-data-from-generic-rest-apis.html#rest)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandoc gives you full control over the the output via filters. The following is a [Lua filter](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html) which uses the HTML/CSS method to hide/show footnotes. See this [R Studio article](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/docs/articles/lua-filters.html) on how to use Lua filters with bookdown.

```lua
-- how many notes we've seen yet.
local note_number = 0

local fn_opening_template = [[<span id="fn-%d"><!--
--><label for="fn-%d-toggle"><sup>%d</sup></label><!--
--><input type="checkbox" hidden id="fn-%d-toggle"/>
]]
local fn_close = '</span>'

local style_css = [[<style>
input[type=checkbox][id|=fn] + span {display:none;}
input[type=checkbox][id|=fn]:checked + span {display:block;}
</style>
]]

-- Use custom HTML for footnotes.
function Note (note)
  note_number = note_number + 1
  local fn_open = fn_opening_template:format(
    note_number, note_number, note_number, note_number)
  return {
    pandoc.RawInline('html', fn_open),
    pandoc.Span(
      pandoc.utils.blocks_to_inlines(note.content),
      pandoc.Attr(string.format('fn-%d-content', note_number))
    ),
    pandoc.RawInline('html', fn_close)
  }
end

function Meta (meta)
  local header_includes = meta['header-includes']
  -- ensure that header_includes is a MetaList
  if not header_includes then
    header_includes = pandoc.MetaList{}
  elseif header_includes.t ~= 'MetaList' then
    header_includes = pandoc.MetaList {header_includes}
  end
  table.insert(
    header_includes,
    pandoc.MetaBlocks{pandoc.RawBlock('html', style_css)}
  )
  meta['header-includes'] = header_includes
  return meta
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm very unfamiliar with Lua filters, so apologies in advance if I've missed something. I added the Lua filter above (repo and rendered example are updated), but the footnote doesn't have the option to show/hide. Rather, it now just always shows directly after the footnote number in the text. I see this has successfully restructured the HTML code, so maybe I am missing some needed CSS?

Comment: I hadn't checked with bookdown, maybe there is a problem with the way the CSS is inserted. Could you try adding the content of `style_css`, i.e., the part between `[[` and `]]` via a separate file as described [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/html-css.html)?

Comment: That did the trick! I also added some additional styling to make the footnote noticeably different than the surrounding text (updated example [here](https://bd-reprex.netlify.app/intro.html)). The only thing missing is the footnote number changing to an "x" when the footnote is expanded to display, but I can live without that for now. Thanks!